# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable optimization

Tags: gurobi

I'm trying to solve an optimization problem, but I have problem with my vars.. so the error is

Tou.addConstr(gp.quicksum(periodos[i] - Curvapu[i] for i in dia)==0)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

The code is bellow

```
Tou = gp.Model('Time of Use')
# Costumer interchangeable parammeter
alpha = 0.80
# Quantity of Load each period
periodos = {}
for i in range(dia):
    periodos[i] = Tou.addVar(vtype=GRB.CONTINUOUS, lb=0, ub=1)

Tou.update()


#Interch = Tou.addConstr((periodos[i] <= alpha*Curvapu[i] for i in range(dia)), name='Interch')

for t in range (dia):
    Tou.addConstr(periodos[t] <= alpha*Curvapu[t])

Tou.addConstr(gp.quicksum(periodos[i] - Curvapu[i] for i in dia)==0)
#Tou.addConstr(np.sum(periodos) - np.sum(Curvapu)==0)

Tou.update()


obj = gp.quicksum(Costo[i] * periodos[i] for i in dia)
Tou.setObjective(obj, GRB.MINIMIZE)
Tou.optimize()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `range(dia)` in the "for" loops. Apparently `dia` is an "int". You also don't need the `Tou.update()` calls. Gurobi will accept new data just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. Now I'm having a new problem with Gurobipy                                               ` File, line 95, in <module>
    obj = gp.quicksum(Costo[i] * periodos[i] for i in range(dia))

  File "gurobi.pxi", line 3255, in gurobipy.quicksum

  File "linexpr.pxi", line 457, in gurobipy.LinExpr.__iadd__

  File "linexpr.pxi", line 173, in gurobipy.LinExpr.add

GurobiError: Unsupported type (<class 'numpy.ndarray'>) for LinExpr addition argument `

Comment: Please check the [examples that come with the Gurobi distribution and read the documentation](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/examples/examples.html). It does not look like you are doing anything out of the ordinary in your model, so I am sure you will find example code for your use-case.